# Is there a way to have TWO axis with DIFFERENT labels in MATPLOTLIB?

Tags: matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm trying to create a plot that has one x-axis on the bottom with text-based labels and I want another one on the top, that has different text-based labels.

The closest thing I found so far are 'secondary_axis' ([Link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.secondary_xaxis)), but when I try to fill in text-based labels, a `TypeError: unhashable type: numpy.ndarray` is raised.

I produced a the following sample based on some code from [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# sphinx_gallery_thumbnail_number = 2

vegetables = ["cucumber", "tomato", "lettuce", "asparagus",
              "potato", "wheat", "barley"]
farmers = ["Farmer Joe", "Upland Bros.", "Smith Gardening",
           "Agrifun", "Organiculture", "BioGoods Ltd.", "Cornylee Corp."]
vegetables_to_farmers = dict(zip(vegetables, farmers))
farmers_to_vegetables = dict(zip(farmers, vegetables))

harvest = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
                    [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
                    [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 3.1, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
                    [1.3, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1],
                    [0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.9, 6.3]])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(harvest)

# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(farmers)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(vegetables)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(farmers)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")


def vegetables2farmers(x):
    return vegetables_to_farmers[x]

def farmers2vegetables(x):
    return farmers_to_vegetables[x]

secax = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(vegetables2farmers, farmers2vegetables))


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

It would be optimal to have the vegetables as labels in the top bar. Do you have any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the concept of axes scales with axes labels. The function and its inverse for a `secondary_axis` is meant to transform the coordinates, not the labels.

In principle using a secondary axis would be nice, if it allowed to set a different formatter. This is unfortunately not the case as of now.

An alternative could be the use of a twin axes. But that won't work for axes with equal aspect.

So as a last resort, one could just create a new axes on top of the old one and format it consistently:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vegetables = ["cucumber", "tomato", "lettuce", "asparagus",
              "potato", "wheat", "barley"]
farmers = ["Farmer Joe", "Upland Bros.", "Smith Gardening",
           "Agrifun", "Organiculture", "BioGoods Ltd.", "Cornylee Corp."]

farmers_to_vegetables = dict(zip(farmers, vegetables))

harvest = np.array([[0.8, 2.4, 2.5, 3.9, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0],
                    [2.4, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.7, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [1.1, 2.4, 0.8, 4.3, 1.9, 4.4, 0.0],
                    [0.6, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 3.1, 0.0, 0.0],
                    [0.7, 1.7, 0.6, 2.6, 2.2, 6.2, 0.0],
                    [1.3, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.2, 5.1],
                    [0.1, 2.0, 0.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.9, 6.3]])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(harvest)

# We want to show all xticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(farmers)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(farmers)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, label="secondary")
ax2.set_aspect("equal")
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax2.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False,
                top=True, labeltop=True)
ax2.set_facecolor("none")
for _, spine in ax2.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(False)

ax2.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax2.set_xticklabels([farmers_to_vegetables[x.get_text()] for x in ax.get_xticklabels()])
plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="left",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]